# Installer can't create sqlite database

Tags: database, installation

I have a drupal page, hosted with azure webapps, on nginx. However, when i start the site, the installer wants to have a database. I am aware that it's bad, but sqlite is an intentional choice because of company reasons.

However, when i try to use sqlite it says it locked.
[image]

I have no direct access to the files, once they are deployed. All changes have to be made locally, and then commited and pushed for azure to redeploy it.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ensure PHP meeets [the requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/system-requirements/database-server-requirements#s-sqlite). Then, read more carefully the instructions on the install screen, which read:

> The **absolute path** to the file where Drupal data will be stored. This **must be writable by the web server** and should exist outside of the web root.

The screenshot you provided does not show an absolute path.

Comment: I checked my sqlite version, and it was higher then the requirements (3.35.4). I also fixed the filepath to the default. Nothing changed about it.

Comment: The web server needs to be able to write to the database file, and the folder it’s in, there’s no way to get around that. If your hosting doesn’t allow that you either need different hosting, or a different db backend

Comment: Is there any way to check if it is able to write to it?